# Smarty value of array extraction using date_format result on other array value as a key

Tags: php, smarty

I have two arrays in a smarty template: $months and $contract.

### {$months|var_dump} gets this:

> array (size=12)
> 1 => string 'января' (length=12)
> 2 => string 'февраля' (length=14)
> 3 => string 'марта' (length=10)
> 4 => string 'апреля' (length=12)
> 5 => string 'мая' (length=6)
> 6 => string 'июня' (length=8)
> 7 => string 'июля' (length=8)
> 8 => string 'августа' (length=14)
> 9 => string 'сентября' (length=16)
> 10 => string 'октября' (length=14)
> 11 => string 'ноября' (length=12)
> 12 => string 'декабря' (length=14)

array values are russian names of months in genitive.

### {$contract|var_dump} gets this

> 'date_till' => '1355518365' (length=10)

so I need to create a month number first from $contract.date_till. it is usually done like

```
{$contract.date_till|date_format:"%m"}
```

And now the question is: **how do I extract a month name from $months array by the month number made of $contract.date_till with date_format?**

I've tried many variants described in smarty manuals, but noone works. For example, this one doesn't:
{$months[{$contract.date_till|date_format:"%m"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{assign var=monthNo value=$contract.date_till|date_format:"%m"}

{$months.$monthNo} 
This will give u the month of the necessary date.

Comment: Unlike english, in russian we have special "grammatical cases" of every noun in every use case in sentence. %B gives me the nominative case but I need the genitive one. That's why I decided to pass all needed cases to smarty via created manually array.

Comment: Then have a month array that has array("January"=>"Russian Equivalent") and so on till December and make it available to your smarty file.
Then write 
{assign var=monthName value=$contract.till_date|date_format:"%B"}
{$month.$monthName} should give the month in russian

Comment: Thank you, your variant works fine, but is too difficult to use it every single time I want to output a month name. Anyway, great thx for interest in my problem.

Comment: You can check your locale settings using locale -a in the server and check if russian language is installed, else install russian language.
Write setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU') in your php file and your month names will display by itself in russian in your smarty file when {$contract.till_date|date_format:"%B"} is used.